# Modifying a widget that was formerly embedded in a tkinter text widget produces an error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm experimenting with re-using widgets that were once embedded in a tkinter text widget. In my code, I add 2 radiobuttons to the text widget. I then added a button that removes the 2nd radiobutton from the text widget. After its removal, I attempt to modify the text of the removed radiobutton. When I do, I get the following error:

> line 1629, in _configure
> self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!text.rb2

I'm really puzzled why my code produces this error and what can be done to fix the problem.
Here's my test code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frm = Frame()
frm.pack()

var = IntVar()

sb = Scrollbar(frm, orient=VERTICAL)
sb.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE )

text = Text(frm,  yscrollcommand=sb.set)
text.pack(expand=True, side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
sb.config(command = text.yview)
rbparent=text
rb1 = Radiobutton(rbparent, name="rb1", text="Radio Button 1", value=1)
rb1.pack()
text.window_create(END, window=rb1)
text.insert(END,'\n')

rb2 = Radiobutton(rbparent, name="rb2", text="Radio Button 2", value=2)
rb2.pack()
text.window_create(END, window=rb2)
text.insert(END,'\n')

def onClick():
    print(text.window_names())
    text.delete('2.0',END)
    print(text.window_names())
    rb2.pack_forget()
    #The following statement produces the error
    rb2.config(text="Modified Radio Button 2")
    print(f"rb2.text:{rb2['text']}")
    print()
    print("onClick Finished...")

Button(frm, text="Click Me", command=onClick).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the for what it's worth department, I've experimented with not removing the embedded radiobutton from the text widget and the modification to the radiobutton's text attribute is successful. The problem only occurs when I remove the embedded radiobutton from the text widget.

Is there a way to modify the attributes of an embedded radiobutton widget after its been removed from a text widget?

Comment: Why are you using `text.window_create(...)` on a widget that you called `.pack()` on? You shouldn't use more than one of these per widget: `.grid()`/`.place()`/`.pack()`/ `.create_window(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I really  didn't fully understand the implication of the text window. I'll remove the pack statement going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm really puzzled why my code produces this error

It's because you're deleting the widget with this line of code:

```
text.delete('2.0',END)
```

This is what the canonical documentation says about calling `delete`: *"If the range of text containing the embedded window is deleted then the window is destroyed."*

If you want to remove the embedded widget from the text widget without destroying it, you can do it like this:

```
text.window_configure('2.0', window='')
```

Comment: Why doesn't the `rb2.pack_forget()` raise the error?

Comment: @TheLizzard: probably because the python object representing the widget still exists and thus the method exists, and in the underlying tcl code `pack_forget` doesn't try to call any methods on the widget. In the tcl/tk code, `pack_forget` isn't a method on a widget, it's a standalone function that accepts a widget name, which it removes from a list of widgets managed by `pack`.

Comment: The python object for the widget is always alive because it's in the global scope. But the `tcl` code not acting on the actual widget makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Finding a way to remove the widget without destroying it was the solution I was looking for. I've tested it and it works perfectly.